# how to write into a text file from python 3.3?

Tags: python

I would like to write 'yes it does' into a text file I made earlier. when I run my code, it says 'AttributeError: **exit**'. I was wondering how to remove this error and make it work successfully, thanks for the help.

The code is:

```
file = ()

def rewrite_test():
    open ('testing.txt', 'rb+')
    with ('testing.txt'):
        print ("yes it does")

rewrite_test()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
def rewrite_test():
    with open('testing.txt', 'w+') as fout:
        fout.write('Yes it does.')
```

Where you had `with ('testing.txt')`, that would raise an exception because the string 'testing.txt' isn't something that supports the requirements of a `with` block.

Also you need to open a file for *writing* not reading, so use 'w' instead of 'r'.

Comment: @inferno_burger, you can use what I put in my answer. `with` is a good thing to use, but put `with open('testing.txt', 'w+')` instead of `with ('testing.txt'):`

Answer (score -1):

If you don't like using with, you can use the following code:

```
def rewrite_test() :
    f = open('testing.txt', 'w') # You can replace w with a if you want to append
    f.write('Yes, it does')
    f.close()

rewrite_test()
```

So it just opens the file, writes to it, and closes it. Also works in Python 2, which doesn't get with. (I am also a Python 2 user, and I don't understand what with does or is.)

Comment: I looked around for a bit and i tried using that sort of coding but it didnt work properly because i use 3.3.0. Thank you for the help though(:

Comment: `with` was added to Python 2.6, but it's available in 2.5 if you `from __future__ import with_statement`. And it looks like inferno_burger wants to append to a file created earlier, so you need to open the file in append mode, using 'w+'.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, added that in, @PM 2Ring